# Как запустить Opera через Selenium Webdriver на Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

Собственно, вопрос в топике. Пробовал заменить все chrome на opera в шаблоне на Хром, но кажется нюанс в том чтобы указать Binary. 
option.setBinary не воспринимается.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Вот шаблон для запуска Opera на JS:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var opera = require('selenium-webdriver/opera');

var options = new opera.Options();
options.setOperaBinaryPath("C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\51.0.2830.34\\opera.exe");
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('opera')
    .setOperaOptions(options)
    .build();

By=webdriver.By, until=webdriver.until, Key = webdriver.Key;

driver.sleep(3000).then(function(){console.log('aeeee')});
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```